# Wordpress и ссылки на localhost

Tags: wordpress, localhost, lamp

Есть 2 компьютера в локальной сети. Первый - Ubuntu server\lamp\wordpress другой клиент. Если с сервера зайти на страницу wordpress - все нормально. Если зайти с клиента - html файл подгружается, но без оформления и у всех ссылок начало адреса подменено с актуального ip : 192.168.0.2 на localhost.

Comment: в чём состоит вопрос?

Comment: Надо чтобы на сервере адрес в wordpress был прописан как `http://localhost`. Тогда при обращении к нему по ip или доменному имени Apach сам поменяет адрес на нужное значение.

Comment: Из последнего абзаца- "  Если зайти с клиента - html файл подгружается, но без оформления и у всех ссылок начало адреса подменено с актуального ip : 192.168.0.2 на localhost.". То есть я с сервера захожу на сервер - вижу нормальный сайт. Если захожу с клиентского - то вижу только html каркас в текстовом формате. Без оформления. Все ссылки видут на localhost.На пример : "http://localhost/wordpress/?p=1#comments". Как исправить это ? Что бы в место localhost был реальный адрес.

Answer (score 1):

1. На сервере у апач должен быть настроен хост по имени которого будет отдаваться нужная директория, к примеру по имени site.lo обрабатывать содержимое /var/www/site.lo, где лежит WP.
2. У второго компьютера в хостах прописать IP_адрес первого компьютера для хоста site.lo
3. Заходить на сайт со второго компьютера по адресу http://site.lo

Сам работаю, по такой схеме... Что вам требуется пока не понятно...